# Make the text center of its frame (above, below, left, right) in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text

i have searched all the web but nothing change. They usually show text center in picture not its frame. The frame of text i use to with other layer. Like my demo.

[image]

I would make the text center of its frame both horizontal and vertical. So how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

There are probably much better ways to do it in AI. In Photoshop, you can use <kbd>Type</kbd> > <kbd>Convert to Point Text</kbd> to create a much tighter BB...

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. But i can't find Create Outling nor Area Type Options in my PTS CS6? How could i?

Comment: @SevenT Blahh...I made a mistake, you were saying PS...I can figure out a new way, just wait...

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop is not the best tool for laying out text. InDesign is much better suited for this task, and it can easily accomplish that.

There's two solutions in Photoshop, neither will be answer that you're looking for.

**Solution 1**

This is more of a hack than a solution.

Set the line-height to be very high so it will be vertically centered, and add a line break above your text (press enter). This will only work for one-lined text boxes and is not modular outside of that.

**Solution 2**

This is the only real solution. Ditch the bounding box, and use the Move tool to align text.

Steps:

1. Make sure your bounding box is the exact height of your text lines.
2. Select the Move tool (Press V)
3. Select the text layer
4. Make a selection out of the background object (ctrl-click the layer)
5. Use the alignment tools in the toolbar to center horizontally and
   vertically (screenshot of what you're looking for below)

[image]

These steps on average take about 1-2 seconds if you're quick about it, I do this all the time in Photoshop. Bounding boxes are pretty worthless and should only be used for pasting large amounts of filler text, in my opinion.

You will have to re-align text if it goes beyond one line using this approach. There's no real way around it using Photoshop.